# Unity + UMA Power tools 2.10 - issues with saving prefabs

Tags: unity

I just got familiar how to work with UMA 2 and I personally would like to use those characters as prefabs so bought the power tools package as well.

I managed to figure out how to save the dcs to prefab but prefab is missing the mesh. Any idea what I'm missing? Downloaded UMA 2 + power tools today so I don't think that it's version issue as well.

Screenshot from unity added

characters should be the same

[image: save prefab missing mesh]

Thanks already in advance!

Steps to reproduce:

1. install uma 2 + uma 2 power tools assets
2. Create new scene
3. Drag UMA_DCS and UMADynamicCharacterAvatar prefabs to scene from UMA/Getting Started
4. Modified the UMADCA to be human female with no wardrope
5. Press play from unity
6. Click the UMADCA to be active
7. From menu press UMA -> Powertools -> Save Characters Prefab
8. Choose location
9. Drag newly created prefab to scene
10. Result is empty character with needed assets (textures etc)

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps you took to get this result?

Comment: Definitely. Just a second. I'll update the steps

Comment: Added the steps. Tried couple of times and end result is always the same

Comment: just now tried with completely new project and the end result is the same

Comment: Doing this in Play mode strikes me as odd. Is that a requirement for this tool?

Comment: At least I got that impression after watching this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6awPZqQ3bZI